# OpenAPi DateTime with timezone information

Tags: datetime, swagger, openapi, datetimeoffset, swagger-editor

I am creating OpenApi Doc for an API.
Having a model object field with DateTime info with timezone.
Example: "2021-12-30T10:00:00+00:00"
The expected input date should be in UTC.

If I use the format: "date-time" then the corresponding generated example is "2021-12-30T10:00:00.123z" where timezone information is missing.

Please suggest the right format to use in the OpenApi spec so that I can get the desired DateTime with a timezone value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"2021-12-30T10:00:00.123z" ends with a 'z'.
This means this DateTime represents UTC time.

[z stands for Zulu Timezone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time#Time_zones)

> UTC is sometimes known as "Zulu time"